# does a JTable have to display all the data from a TableModel?

Tags: java, swing

Am struggling a bit with an (admittedly poor) design if anyone wouldn't mind giving some advice.

I've a form that adds people to a database. The database is displayed in a JTable, which uses a custom TableModel that is updated via a controller (rather than having a reference to the model in the JTable). When you click a row in the table, data from the selected row is displayed on a detailsPanel using `table.getValueAt(row,col)`

My problem here is that I want the detailsPanel to display a more detailed version of the person/db entry.The TableModel is passed an array of People, so I guess I could just implement a method in the TableModel that retrieves the information I want, but I'm not sure how.

Basically I don't know how to click on a row in the JTable and retreive data that the TableModel has access to, but isn't displayed in the table itself (in this case each Person instance has a CV URI that I want to retrieve). My best effort so far - adding the line `case 10: return p.getCvURI();` returns an index out of bounds exception, and demonstrates my limited understanding of exactly how table models work.

Here's the TableModel class:

```
package gui;

import model.Person;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CandidateTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
private List<Person> data = new ArrayList<Person>();
private String[] colNames = {"ID","Title","Name","Surname","Address 1","Address 2","Address 3",
                "Postcode","Employment Status","Search Status"};

public CandidateTableModel(){}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column){
    return colNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(){
    return 10;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount(){
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column){
    Person p = data.get(row);
    switch(column){
        case 0: return p.getID();
        case 1: return p.getTitle();
        case 2: return p.getFName();
        case 3: return p.getSName();
        case 4: return p.getAddress1();
        case 5: return p.getAddress2();
        case 6: return p.getAddress3();
        case 7: return p.getPostcode();
        case 8: return p.getEmpStatus();
        case 9: return p.getSearchStatus();
    }
    return null;
}

public void setData(List<Person> data){
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

If anyone could give me some pointers it would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, just add a `Person getPerson(int row) { return data.get(row); }` to your table model. I don't understand what the concrete problem is. The enclosing class could also simply keep a reference to the `data` list it passes to the table model. Get the index of the clicked row, convert it to a model row, and get the person at that index in the list.

Comment: I think the problem is undoubtedly a) poor design (a side effect of me trying to separate everything to better learn communicating between components) which is why I'm not simply using a model reference in the table view, and b) a lack of real understanding of how table models work. Thanks, I'll try that now

Comment: yeah, worked perfectly. i'm clearly not thinking straight. i'll blame it on too much coffee. thanks though